# Bootstrap modal can't show DatePicker, also with huge z-index

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-datepicker

Having this modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="nuovohotelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="favoritesModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <label>Aggiungi nuovo hotel</label>
          <form action="{{route('addHotelCP',$data[0]->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="CPID" name="idCP" value="{{ $data[0]->id }}">
            <input type="hidden" id="clienteid" name="idClienteFk" value="{{ $data[0]->idClienteFk }}">

            <label for="hotel">
              Struttura alberghiera
            </label>
            <select class="form-control" id="HotelidCompagniaFk" name="idHotelFk">
              <option value="0">
                Seleziona una struttura alberghiera
              </option>
              @foreach ($data[4] as $hotelS)

              <option value="{{$hotelS->id}}">
                {{$hotelS->nome}}
              </option>

              @endforeach
            </select>
            <div class="form-group" onclick="addDatepicker()" id="newhoteldatapickerdataIn">
              <label for="dataIn">Data di arrivo:</label>
              <div class="input-group date">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newhoteldataIn" name="dataIn" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id="newhoteldatapickerdataOut">
              <label for="dataOut">Data di rientro:</label>
              <div class="input-group date">

                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newhoteldataOut" name="dataOut" />
              </div>
            </div>

            <label for="trattamento">Trattamento:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newHoteltrattamento" name="trattamento" />

            <label for="commissioni">Commissioni:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newHotelcommissioni" name="commissioni" />

            <label for="buy">Buy:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newHotelbuy" name="buy" />
            <label for="sell">Sell:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newHotelsell" name="sell" sell/>
            <label for="bar">BAR:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newHotelbar" name="bar" bar/>

            <label for="istruzioni">Istruzioni:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="newHotelistruzioni" name="istruzioni" />

            <label for="status">Stato:</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="status" id="newHotelstatus">
              <option value="0">
                Seleziona uno stato
              </option>
              @foreach($data[12] as $status)

              <option value="{{$status->id}}" >
                {{$status->nome}}
              </option>

              @endforeach
            </select>
            <br />
            <br/>
            <br/>

            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" value="Aggiungi nuovo hotel" />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the related jQuery portion called in document.ready:

```
$('#newhoteldatapickerdataIn .input-group date').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});

$('#newhoteldatapickerdataOut .input-group date').datepicker({
  format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
});
```

If I click on the two date fields, it won't appear the datepicker' calendar.

As mentioned in the question title, I've also enforced the z-index:

```
body.modal-open .datepicker {
  z-index: 99999999 !important;
  width: 80%;
  height: 85%;
}

.datepicker.dropdown-menu {
  z-index: 100000 !important;
}

.datepicker {
  z-index: 100000 !important;
}
```

And to be sure, this css enforcement will be applied:

[image]

I've also tried to enforce the creation of datepicker when it'll be fired the onclick on the field itself, with no success.

The screenshot of Chrome, is related to another datepicker shown correctly in the page, the problem affects only the datepickers inside the modal window.

I tried also to enforce the creations of the two datepicker when the modal will be opened:

```
$("#nuovohotelModal").on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {

  $('#newhoteldatapickerdataIn .input-group date').datepicker({
    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    language: "it"
  });

  $('#newhoteldatapickerdataOut .input-group date').datepicker({

    format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
    autoclose: true,
    language: "it"
  });

});
```

Comment: What I think it is happening is that the position is not the same in the modal, this means that probably using top: 618px and left:31px cause that it goes outside the modal. Can you please try to put other values? Also, if you put the mouse over the datepicker in the HTML you should see where is the HTML element in the page.

Comment: That position is relative to the element where the click has been done. If I force it, for example to 50% and 50%, won't work either.

Comment: I tried also to search the dropdown menù in the DOM with this class: "datepicker datepicker-dropdown dropdown-menu datepicker-orient-left datepicker-orient-top", when it's opened by a field in the page it will be generated, when I try to do the same stuff on a modal, won't.